# Jfrog Terraform provider data source issue

Tags: docker, terraform, artifactory

[image]I’m trying to use the Terraform provider for Jfrog and use data source to retrieve information from a docker repo.  The screenshot is attached.

I was able to connect to the Jfrog repository and authenticate successfully.
But I’m not able to get the artifactory file details with the data source,

```
data "artifactory_fileinfo" "testfile" {
  repository = "config-docker"
  #path       = "config-docker/main/configsvc/0.0.0-20230327.180/sha256__3d8542e106c08e1c10fdb05a14985f56bf25a0b65d832c46ab77aec9b8"
  #path       = "test-config-docker/main/configsvc/0.0.0-20230327.180/manifest.json"
  path = https://test.jfrog.io/artifactory/onfig-docker/main/configsvc/0.0.0-20230327.180/manifest.json
}
```

However I try it gives the error

```
│ {
│   "errors" : [ {
│     "status" : 404,
│     "message" : "Unable to find item"
│   } ]
│ }
│
│   with data.artifactory_fileinfo.testfile,
│   on main.tf line 31, in data "artifactory_fileinfo" "testfile":
│   31: data "artifactory_fileinfo" "testfile" {
│
```

Should the path value in terraform need to have the repository path od the url to file? I tried both ways but didn't work. Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong?